# Select node based on sibling's value

Tags: xml, xpath

I need XPath syntax (for use in simplexml) for searching the contents of the `LayoutPosNo` element that matches exactly, say, the number 1001 and returning the text in the sibling `Descrip` element.  The `LayoutPosNo`'s are all unique, so I only need the first match.

Here is the structure of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <LayoutPosNo>10</LayoutPosNo>
        <Descrip>This is the red room</Descrip>
    </record>
    <record>
        <LayoutPosNo>993</LayoutPosNo>
        <Descrip>This is the yellow room</Descrip>
    </record>
    <record>
        <LayoutPosNo>1001</LayoutPosNo>
        <Descrip>This is the purple room</Descrip>
    </record>
</data-set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath

```
/data-set/record[LayoutPosNo = 1001]/Descrip/text()
```

will select

```
This is the purple room
```

as requested.